# No Counter Theorem1 is defined

Tags: errors, numbering, theorems, counters

I got an exception in the following latex code: "No Counter Theorem1 is defined", what is the problem?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\newtheorem{definition}[theorem1]{Definition}
\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
%\boldmath
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}




\section{Introduction}
\begin{definition}[dd]
sdfa
\end{definition}


\end{document}
```

Comment: In my case, `\usepackage{cleveref}` caused that error. After removing that package, everything worked as expected.

Comment: @koppor have you tried to load first the `amsthm` package? (i.e., write `\usepackage{amsthm}`  before `\usepackage{cleveref}` . That helped. :)

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus this worked for me, thanks. I was using an external cls file which automatically loaded `cleveref` before I could load `amsthm`, so I had to disable the automatic loading and explicitly load `cleveref` myself after I loaded `amsthm` (might be helpful for anyone who's having trouble with the LIPIcs style class)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have declared a new theorem type "Definition" which uses the counter of the theorem type "theorem1" -- but such a type hasn't been declared. The following works:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\newtheorem{theorem1}{Special Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem1]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{theorem1}
foo
\end{theorem1}

\begin{definition}[dd]
sdfa
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use a number in the name of the type. This will break if some command try to use e.g. `\thetheorem1`.