# Why am i getting a counter error while defining a Theorem environment?

Tags: theorems

I have this in a latex file:

```
   \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
```

and at some point i have this:

```
\begin{theorem}
foo
\end{theorem}
```

but i am getting this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'Theorem' defined.
```

Comment: I get the error `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

Comment: if you add `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` to what you have here, it finishes with no errors.  please provide a complete, but non-working, example.

Comment: I can't post a complete document. My document makes numerous includes and is structured.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate question to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64860/no-counter-theorem1-is-defined

Answer (score 2):

Please always post *complete* documents that show the problem.

The code you show does not produce the error you describe.

This document *does* produce that error

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[Special Theorem]

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
foo
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

and the solution is to remove the `[Special Theorem]`

Comment: Sorry my fault. I changed the question appropriately

Comment: @curious your edit does not help. Please post a complete documet that shows the error